# CasperJS is too slow because of too many navigation requests

Tags: javascript, request, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

As we know we can abort a resource request in CasperJS, like this:

```
casper.on('page.resource.requested', function(requestData, request) {
  if(/plusone|google\.com|about:blank/.test(requestData.url)){
    this.echo("----I can ignore this------");
    request.abort();
  }
});
```

But I found it too slow (it might take hours to open a page) because of too many navigation requests, the type of most of them is `Reload`, I want something like this:

```
casper.on('navigation.requested', function(url, navigationType, navigationLocked, isMainFrame) {
  utils.dump(arguments);
  if(/plusone|google\.com|about:blank/.test(url)){
    this.echo("!!!-----------------------------Can I abort the request?---------------------!!!");
    // request.abort();
  }
});
```

I searched whole day in Google, and got nothing. This drives me crash.

Comment: Disable Image make it a bit faster too : casper.options.pageSettings.loadImages = false;

Comment: Yes, I did so, but still is toooo slow

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: set loadImages: false
    loadPlugins: false
    javascriptEnabled: false
can increase page loading, I think the main performance was blocked on javascript loading, especially when the page has iframe.

Comment: Me too, how to solve it ?